# Function caller positional parameters

Tags: bash, shell, parameter, function, shopt

I need to read and write the positional parameters `$@` of a function's caller. The Bash man page says that:

> A shell function is an object that is called like a simple command and
>   executes a compound command with a new set of positional parameters

So `$@` is rewritten at every call. I looked for some "special parameter" but found nothing. The shell variable `BASH_ARGV` seems to solve my problem, however it requires `shopt -s extdebug` enabled, what isn't the default behavior in my machine neither looks like a option to turn on in production.

```
extdebug
    If set, behavior intended for use by debuggers is enabled:
    ...
    4.     BASH_ARGC and BASH_ARGV are updated as described in their
           descriptions above.
    ...
```

Is Bash capable of read or write a function's caller `$@` without `BASH_ARGV`? Do you think that Bash is limited and use another shell for scripting?

**Edit:** I want a fancy `getopt` wrapper inside my helper library. So all behavior related to it goes inside a function. No need to check errors or `set --`.

Comment: How to format the citation block like a man page?

Comment: You can just pass the parent `$@` explicitly to the function: `func "$@"`.

Comment: And if I need to rewrite it?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Read and write the parent `$@`. I'm writing a wrapper around `getopt` for aesthetic purposes.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Sounds like an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341)

Comment: [I found a use case](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320598/how-can-i-choose-one-of-locates-results-and-let-it-be-opened-with-a-specified/320707#320707) and a roundabout way to do something like it (see my edited answer).

Answer (score 2):

A function cannot affect its caller's positional parameters. This is by design: positional parameters are meant to be private to the function.

Make your function work on an array.

```
myfunction () {
  local _myfunction_arrayname=$1
  shift
  … # work on the positional parameters
  eval "$_myfunction_arrayname=(\"\$@\")"
}
myfunction foo "$@"
set -- "${foo[@]}"
```

In ksh93 and bash, there's a roundabout way to do something approaching by combining an alias and the `.` (`source`) builtin with a process substitution. [Example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320598/how-can-i-choose-one-of-locates-results-and-let-it-be-opened-with-a-specified/320707#320707).

```
alias myfunction='. <(echo myfunction_body \"\$@\"; echo set -- "\"\${new_positional_parameters[@]}\"")'
```

Put the meat of the work of the function in `myfunction_body` and make it set the array `new_positional_parameters`. After a call to `myfunction`, the positional parameters are set to the values that `myfunction_body` puts in `new_positional_parameters`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some [code which loops through the parameters, updating each of them as necessary](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/.bash_aliases#L76-81). In this case, replacing duplicate slashes with a single one:

```
for param
do
    param="$(printf %s. "$1" | tr -s "/")"
    set -- "$@" "${param%.}"
    shift
done
```

Comment: Off topic question, but why not `set -- "${@//\/+(\/)//}"` instead of all that? (Note that requires `shopt -s extglob`, which is off by default for non-interactive shells.)

Comment: @manatwork Nice one-liner for this specific situation. It's just a (verbose) demonstration of how to do arbitrary modification to the parameters.