# How can I choose one of `locate`'s results and let it be opened with a specified application

Tags: bash, shell-script, menu, locate

I have a bash script called `findme`, which is coded as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
locate -Abi '*\.'$1 $2 | grep --color=always -ni $2 | less -R
```

It searches for me for all files with a specified file extension (first argument provided to the script) which has a pattern (the next provided argument) in its filename.
If I execute the following:

```
user@machine$ findme pdf classifi
```

It will search for all `pdf` files with `classifi` in its filename. So I may get something like the following result.

> 1:/home/user/Dropbox/SharedWithFriends/math/**classifi**cations2000.pdf
>   2:/home/user/Dropbox/SharedWithFriends/math/**classifi**cations2010.pdf

**The question is:** *"Can you give me a bash script code in which after showing the results ask me for a number and a viewer, to automate my next job?"*

for example I would like, if I enter:

```
> 2 evince
```

the script executes `evince` on the `2`nd item of the search result, *i.e.*,
if this is what I entered on the previous search result it executes:

```
evince /home/user/Dropbox/SharedWithFriends/math/classifications2010.pdf
```

Comment: do you imagine changing `findme` to have a prompt at the end for you to enter the item # and viewer, or would you leave `findme` unchanged and instead have a separate, second function `openme` that accepted `2 evince` as parameters?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a variation on your `findme` function that pulls up the results, but instead of using `grep` to number them, or `less` to page them, it lists them from an internal array, then prompts for your item and program choice.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

readarray -O 1 -t results < <(locate -Abi '*\.'"$1" "$2" | grep --color=always -i "$2")

for((i=1; i <= ${#results[*]}; i++))
do
  printf "%d: %s\n" $i "${results[i]}"
done
read -p "> " item program
$program "${results[item]}"
```

I added some quoting to your original script to better deal with spaces in filenames, or even grep parameters. I adjusted the `readarray` call so that the results start at index 1 instead of 0, so that it corresponds to grep's numbering.

Comment: I is great! It is almost what I want! Except it gives me an error... please keep in mind that the results have escape codes! can you fix if for me!?

Comment: Numbering from 0 is also fine!

Comment: I need something to page the results sometime the search result returns me 70 items!

Answer (score 2):

Note that your `findme` script has a few problems:

- [Missing double quotes around variable substitutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)
- The output of `grep --color=always` produces results that can't be used in a command substitution. You need it to pass through `less`, but don't try to reuse it in a script.
- grep and locate use different pattern syntax, so using `grep` to color the second argument won't always work. Passing `-r` to `locate` makes it use regexps, but with Emacs syntax which is slightly different from the syntaxes that grep supports.

In bash, you can use [`mapfile`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-mapfile) to reliably stuff some lines into an array. Combine it with [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) to use the output of a command. Then print that array and read the user's input.

```
findrun () {
  mapfile search_hits <(locate -Abir ".*\.$1" "$2")
  print '%s\n' "${search_hits[@]}" | grep --color=always -ine "$2"
  if read -a cmd; then
    set -- "${cmd[@]}"
    set -- "$@" "${search_hits[$1]}"
    shift
    "$@"
  fi
}
```

An alternative interface would be to set the positional parameters. It's a bit tricky, because you can't change the positional parameters from a function, but there's a [roundabout way to do it in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50654/function-caller-positional-parameters/51866#51866) by using an alias and sourcing a script. Beware of quoting.

```
alias findrun='. <(echo findrun_prepare \"\$@\"; echo set -- "\"\${search_hits[@]}\"")'
findrun_prepare () {
  mapfile search_hits <(locate -Abir ".*\.$1" "$2")
  print '%s\n' "${search_hits[@]}" | grep --color=always -ine "$2" >&2
}
```

Usage:

```
findrun pdf classifi
evince "$2"
```

Comment: Your first code gives me the following error (when I try to run `findrun pdf classifi`): locate: non-option arguments are not allowed with --regexp

Comment: @texinfo Oh, damn, I hadn't tested that. I think my answer would work without `-r`, as long as you accept the inconsistency which won't matter if you only look for strings (e.g. `findrun pdf classifi` as opposed to `findrun pdf cl*ifi`).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Solution given by Jeff Schaller.
I found a solution, I would be glad if I receive your comments, to make it better.

```
#!/bin/bash

readarray -O 1 -t results < <(locate -Abi '*\.'"$1" "$2")

for((i=1; i <= ${#results[*]}; i++))
do
  printf "%d: %s" $i "${results[i]}" | grep --color=always -i "$2"
done

read -p "> " item program

$program "${results[item]}"
```

This looks like a simple (up to complexity of the topics) answer.

**But is not fine enough if the results be more than a certain number! In that case we need something like `more` or `less`**