# How to referencing $@ without pass it in bash function?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I wants to know how can I reference the `$@` from another function or another script
file without pass it just like what `getopts` do. Thank you very much!

# previous question :
[How bash getopts get to know what arguments the call has](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/761984/how-bash-getopts-get-to-know-what-arguments-the-call-has#761985)

```
A() {
  B 
} 

B() {

  # how to reference the $@ of A here ?
  # which will be 1 2 3 4


}

A 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Each function gets its own $@. You could create a new array in "A" and reference it in "B", but the question is "why would you want to do such a thing?". I suspect this is an X-Y problem. Can you tell us what you are trying to do?

Comment: want to write a `getopts ` alike function without pass "A"'s arguments but knowing what "A" has.

Comment: Similar: [Is there a way to get the positional parameters of the script from inside a function in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/418621) and [Function caller positional parameters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/50654) and [Use of positional parameters inside function defintion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/429211)

Comment: I wander what the actual use-case is? Are you just too lazy to pass the parameters again, or what is the issue you are trying to solve? Accessing global variable from a function is generally considered to be poor programming style (exceptions confirming the rule).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't without `A` making its positional parameters available to `B` one way or another. Could be by passing them along:

```
A() {
  B "$@"
}
B() {
  [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '<%s>\n' "$@"
}
```

Or storing them in an array:

```
A() {
  A_args=( "$@" )
  B
}
B() {
  [ "${#A_args[@]}" -eq 0 ] || printf '<%s>\n' "${A_args[@]}"
}
```

As bash, like ash/ksh88/zsh (but unlike ksh93 or zsh's `private` variables) does dynamic scoping for its local variables, you could even make that `A_args` variable `local` to `A` and it would still be available in the functions that `A` calls.

`bash` lets you access *variables* of its parent scope even when they're *shadowed* by local variables in the current scope by exploiting a current bug of its `unset` builtin (which under some conditions doesn't unset but reveal the variable from the parent scope), but you can't access the positional parameters from the parent scope that way because in bash (contrary to `zsh`/`rc`/`fish`...), positional parameters cannot be mapped to array variables as bash array design is shaped after that of the Korn shell where arrays are not really arrays.

If you want some code to be able to access or modify (via `shift` or `set`) the function's positional parameters or local options, or `return` from the function, you need that code to run in the scope of that function, so that cannot be in a separate function.

You could use aliases (which are the shell equivalent of C pre-processor macros, except they can't take arguments) or `eval` though.

Beware though that:

- in the bash shell and when not in POSIX mode, alias expansion is disabled by default so you'll need `shopt -s expand_aliases`.
- the alias must exists *before* the code of the function is read, and it is expanded inside the code of the function.

So you could do:

```
[ -z "$BASH_VERSION" ] || shopt -s expand_aliases # work around for bash
alias B='{
  [ "$#" -eq 0 || printf "<%s>\n" "$@"
  shift
}'
A() {
  echo "$#"
  B
  echo "$#"
}
A a b c
```

Or:

```
B='
  [ "$#" -eq 0 || printf "<%s>\n" "$@"
  shift
'
A() {
  echo "$#"
  eval "$B"
  echo "$#"
}
A a b c
```

Comment: can we posible accomplish something like what the native function `getopts ` do? without pass arguments?

Comment: `getopts` works on the positional parameters from the scope it's called in when not passed any extra arguments, it can't access positional parameters from a parent scope either.

Comment: can you explain this a little bit more? What do you mean by "getopts works on the positional parameters from the scope it's called", can we write a function to do the same? can you give me an example of this?

Comment: What that means is just that if getopts is called in a function, it accesses the positional parameters of the function ($@ expands to the list of positional parameters), that's it. Even zsh which in the latest development version lets you do `nameref var=argv` cannot access positional parameters from a different function scope.

Comment: "getopts is called in a function, it accesses the positional parameters of the function" This is what I want. How getopts  able to access it without predefine?? Do you mean that any function developed by user will not able to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: @Till `getopts` is not a function, it's a shell builtin.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. Any shell code you write will have to run in the scope of the function if it has to be able to access the function's $@ (or return from that function for that matters), so that code can't be in a separate function. You could have that code in a variable and use `eval "$that_variable"` though.

Comment: Got it, thank you very much.

Comment: See edit for approaches using `alias` or `eval`.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, in bash, when the `extdebug` option is enabled (normally used for the debugger), the list of positional parameters of all the functions in the call stack is made available in the `$BASH_ARGV` special array (though in reverse order) with `$BASH_ARGC` containing the number of arguments at each level.

Beware though that:

- those are readonly (well, trying to change their value has no effect)
- the extdebug must be set from the start (before the first function is invoked), but not on the bash command line (<strike>`bash -O extdebug`</strike>) as that invokes the debugger instead.
- check the manual for the other implications of enabling that option.

```
shopt -s extdebug
shopt -u xpg_echo
A() {
  B x y
}

reverse_helper() { caller_args=( "${BASH_ARGV[@]:0:BASH_ARGC}" ); }

B() {
  local -a caller_args
  local IFS=,
  reverse_helper "${BASH_ARGV[@]:BASH_ARGC[0]:BASH_ARGC[1]}"
  echo "my args: $*"
  echo "my caller args: ${caller_args[*]}"
}

A a b c
```

Which gives:

```
my args: x,y
my caller args: a,b,c
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, OP is asking about how to imitate the behaviors of builtins such as `shift` and `getopts` in a function. It's actually possible with some tricks, though I'm not sure it's a good idea to use it in production.

```bash
A() {
  B
} 

B() {
  trap 'shift;trap debug' debug
}

A 1 2 3 4
```

`trap` must be the last command in the function B.

If you want to preserve the original debug trap after return:

```bash
A() {
  B
} 

B() {
  local olddebug="$(trap -p debug)"
  trap "shift;trap debug;$olddebug" debug
}

A 1 2 3 4
```

Compared to aliases, functions could be referenced in another function before defined, called recursively, and redefined and get the new version called in the same function. Aliases would fail if you wrap everything in a script file including the aliases into a big function and call the function, though it's also rarely used in production.

Comment: You'll need to have a command after `B` in the `A` function for that debug trap to be run there. That command should probably not be a subshell.